# Create equivalent of webpage in app. Android

Tags: android

I'm making an app that is the mobile equivalent to a website where a person can answer surveys or comment on discussion forums. I'm using vue in the web project and I'm unsure about how to make the app work in a similar fashion, so far I have the login functionality and through retrofit request I can get all the info in json format for the surveys and forums. How can I display these in a similar way as below (that's the web dash when a user has surveys available to answer) as in each one is a separate thing or "component".

[image]

The way I would like to do it, is when the user click on a survey is takes them to a page where they answer all the questions and send the info back to the server to save in the database. I don't know how to make this in a dynamic way for the items or "components", and also building the survey questions page dynamically?

Right now the app I have is using a navigation drawer and the survey or forum "page" are fragments, I'm not sure if that matters or not but I'm assuming it's good to know.

I know it's a lot but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you trying to develop vue web-app just like you did in Android, am i assuming that? If so, i try answer one by one

1)

> I have the login functionality and through retrofit request I can get
>   all the info in json format for the surveys and forums

RetroFit is Type-safe HTTP client. So equivalent of that would be [**Axios**](https://github.com/axios/axios) in Vue (as long you have API URL to GET request, you're good to pull your datas in whatever format e.g JSON). There is Jquery but might be too much, so i not gonna throw you there.

2)

> when the user click on a survey is takes them to a page where they answer all the questions and send the info back to the server to save in the database

So you have something like Intent in Android for navigation (that's equivalent to [**vue-router**](https://router.vuejs.org/), you will be using **Dynamic Route Matching** e.g `/post/:id` for /post/123 to match postId dynamically to get your route right, along with Axios pull datas )

3) you can treat Android's fragment as Component in Vue, understanding the lifecycle and reactivity of Vue will makes your learning easier as you're good in Android.

Hope helps, Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my main question is how can I create those individual items or "components" for each survey or forum that is in the json, would I still be able to do that with fragments if they are inside another fragment? the landing page for the surveys or forums is already a fragment.

Comment: You just need to make *one* component that reflects your $id of your data, it will serve as general template for your surveys (if their survey structure the same)

E.g  SurveyComponent.vue + set route '/survey/:id' in your router.js file, will allow you to use the component to template your surveys according data pulled like /survey/1, /survey/2 etc. Every component is like instance, has their own lifecycles as u can treat each as different Activity in your Android Term

Comment: after I create those templates, what would be the process of showing them in the main fragment?

Comment: Then this [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/11/pass-data-between-routes-vuejs-web-application/) will helps in passing data via `<router-link>` using URL/Query Parameters :)

Comment: I was asking about how to do this in android not about Vue